# android multiple realm queries with RXJava

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, rx-java2

I'm maintaining an app that I didn't make myself.

The app is running on special android device that can read barcodes using a laser beam and once a barcode was entered the app starts checking through lal of the Realms Data base if such code exists, thing is that search queries are many because the app needs to search for both all small letter and all capital letters barcodes.

Each database item contains 3 barcodes and once UPC code which the search method needs to iterate on all of them and return an answer.

Code below

```
fun readItemByMKTorUPC(Value : String,callback:NewCountingPresenter.findItem{
    doAsync {
    val realm =  Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    var findVal : ItemRealmSearchOnly? = ItemRealmSearchOnly()

    //--------------------MKT-------------------------------
    //search for MKT
    findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT",Value)?.findFirst()


    //if not found search for UPC Upper
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toUpperCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("UPC",Value)?.findFirst()
    }

    //if not found search for MKT Lower Case
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toLowerCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT",Value)?.findFirst()
    }


    //if not found search for MKT UPPER Case
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toUpperCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT",Value)?.findFirst()
    }

    //--------------------UPC-------------------------------
    //if not found search for UPC
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("UPC",Value)?.findFirst()
    }

    //if not found search for UPC Lower
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toLowerCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("UPC",Value)?.findFirst()
    }


   //--------------------MKT 2-------------------------------
    //if not found search for MKT 2
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value;
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT2",Value)?.findFirst()
    }
    //if not found search for MKT 2 Upper
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toUpperCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT2",Value)?.findFirst()
    }
    //if not found search for MKT 2 lower
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toLowerCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT2",Value)?.findFirst()
    }
    //--------------------MKT3-------------------------------
    //if not found search for MKT 3
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toUpperCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT3",Value)?.findFirst()
    }

    //if not found search for MKT 3 Upper
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toUpperCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT3",Value)?.findFirst()
    }


    //if not found search for MKT 3 lower
    if(findVal?.MKT.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val Value :String = Value.toUpperCase();
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java).contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)?.equalTo("MKT3",Value)?.findFirst()
    }

    var item : ItemRealm = ItemRealm();
    item.MKT = findVal?.MKT;
    item.MKT2 = findVal?.MKT2;
    item.MKT3 = findVal?.MKT3;
    item.UPC = findVal?.UPC;
    item.AMOUNT = findVal?.AMOUNT;
    uiThread {

            callback.clickHere(item);
        }

    }
}
```

The issue with this method is that it takes long time to iterate on each of those queries and return an answer to the user

I thought of integrating RxJava 2 method for this code but couldn't find any useful tips how to do it online.

Edit:

I Found a solution thanks to **Tim Castelijns** hinting in the comments

```
        MyApplication.instance.printLog("scanner start: MKT");
        findVal = realm.where(ItemRealmSearchOnly::class.java)
                .contains("company_id",MyApplication.instance.company.companyNameId)
                ?.equalTo("MKT",Value)
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT",Value.toUpperCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT",Value.toLowerCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("UPC",Value)
                ?.or()?.equalTo("UPC",Value.toLowerCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("UPC",Value.toUpperCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT2",Value)
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT2",Value.toLowerCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT2",Value.toUpperCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT3",Value)
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT3",Value.toLowerCase())
                ?.or()?.equalTo("MKT3",Value.toUpperCase())
                ?.findFirst();
        MyApplication.instance.printLog("scanner end: MKT");
```

which improved the search time by atleast 200% than the old method

Comment: rxjava won't make your code faster. You should probably take a step back and think about what the actual requirement is here, and rework the logic. I don't think this code with 10 if's is what you really want. Perhaps you could do with "or" queries

Comment: could you give me an example for "or queries" i never worked with realm before

Comment: No, read the docs

Comment: that won't be faster, but you could possibly put an index on field `MKT` and index on `UPC` to make it faster; just beware the migration

Comment: well Tim even if you are not the nicest person on StackOverflow but atleast you sorta awnsered my question ill post an edit of the way i made the code 200% times faster using only .or()